# Timestamp conversion failing to produce desired result

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, pandas, time

I have a pandas data-frame with a date and a time column, among others, and I am trying to convert both columns into a Unix time stamp with microsecond precision, this is so I can dump the data-frame into a numpy memory map file (which requires floats, or at least not date objects, so it's kind of essential).

So without the data-frame, using only the string, I get the following:

```
DT = '2014-10-01 00:00:07.082000'

UX= time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(DT, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').timetuple())
print UX
>>> 1412118007.0

tm = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(UX)
print tm
>>>2014-10-01 00:00:07
```

So how do I **include** the microseconds with the time stamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast to `np.int64` for unix time with `ns` precision:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['2014-10-01 00:00:07.082000', '2014-10-01 00:00:07.082000']})
print (df)
                            A
0  2014-10-01 00:00:07.082000
1  2014-10-01 00:00:07.082000

df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df.A)

df['B'] = df.A.astype(np.int64)
df['C'] = pd.to_datetime(df.B, unit='ns')
print (df)
                        A                    B                       C
0 2014-10-01 00:00:07.082  1412121607082000000 2014-10-01 00:00:07.082
1 2014-10-01 00:00:07.082  1412121607082000000 2014-10-01 00:00:07.082
```

For `ms` precision use:

```
df['B'] = (df.A.astype(np.int64) // 10**6)
df['C'] = pd.to_datetime(df.B, unit='ms')
print (df)
                        A              B                       C
0 2014-10-01 00:00:07.082  1412121607082 2014-10-01 00:00:07.082
1 2014-10-01 00:00:07.082  1412121607082 2014-10-01 00:00:07.082
```

Answer (score -1):

This will do =)

```
from datetime import datetime


DT = '2014-10-01 00:00:07.082000'

UX = datetime.strptime(DT, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

print UX
>>> 2014-10-01 00:00:07.082000
```

Comment: That is not a time stamp though, that is a date-time object, which cant be stored and read from a .npy file.